# Multiple css3 transition types not using 'all'

Tags: firefox, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to transition both the scale and the opacity using CSS3 transitions - I can't work out how to transition multiple things without using **all**

```
transition-function: all;
transition-duration: 1s;
transition-timing-function: ease-in;
```

works, as does:

```
transition: all 1s ease-in;
```

and

```
transition-function: opacity;
```

or

```
transition-function: scale;
```

but not

```
transition-function: scale, opacity;
```

See the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5PCGs/7/

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks :) !

**Edit:**

I have worked out it's `transition-property` (thanks Simone), but now it's only animating opacity in Firefox, not both - http://jsfiddle.net/5PCGs/9 - compare this in FF and Chrome side-by-side

Comment: ps: I am using vendor-specific prefixes - just omitted them here to cut down on the post length.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to [Boris Zbarsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/720912/boris-zbarsky) and [Simone Vittori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/801544/simone-vittori).

The answer was to use `transition-property` and in not specify all the things you're transforming in there, just put `transform` in as one of the values, and let the differences in the transforms between the classes take care of itself.

```
transition-property: transform,opacity;
transition-duration: 1s;
transition-timing-function: ease-in;
```

**EDIT:** Don't for get to add any prefixes you need to these. For Webkit browsers for example:

```
-webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform,opacity;
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `transition-property` instead of `transition-function`, that actually doesn't exist. :)

Each of the transition properties accepts a comma-separated list, allowing multiple transitions to be defined.

Comment: Yep, there is no transition-function property: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transitions-

Comment: Thanks! That's great. It works now for Chrome, but the scale transition doesn't seem to work for Firefox at all. I shall continue to look!

Comment: Compare this in Firefox and Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/5PCGs/9/

Chrome does it all right, but Firefox won't animate the scale. If you use `-moz-transform: scale(0);` it will, but then I can't include the opacity property in this.

So weird!

Comment: @Trolleymusic you can't transition from no transform (which corresponds to `scale(1)`) to `scale(1)`.  There's nothing to transition.  Using `-moz-transition-property: -moz-transform, opacity` works fine if your transform actually changes.

Comment: @Boris, obviously! :) -- The original state of the box has `transform: scale(0);` and the `.active` has `transform: scale(1);`

But are you saying that rather than use `-moz-transition-property: scale,opacity;` I should use `-moz-transition-property: -moz-transform,opacity;` ?

That's great! Thanks Boris!